# Firebase AppCheck seems verified but queries don't work

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-app-check

I'm not able to get data from a realtime database after verify the appcheck token sent from the frontend layer. Let me explain it more in details.

I've an Angular (front) + Node (back) application connected with Firebase.
My backend layer it's oriented to create an API to connect to a Realtime Database, get the answers, process the data and get back to the frontend.

The libraries:

- "firebase": "^10.7.2"
- "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0"
- Angular: 17.1.0

The application it's working properly without AppCheck integration, but I want to include it to increase my security layer.

Now I'm working always in local, so my backend app and my frontend app are executed in localhost.

[With this in mind, I've a recaptcha enterprise key marked as test/debug.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRvbv.png)

The recaptcha key is attached to my app in firebase console and I've created a debug token also included in debug tokens section.

So, since I've a custom backend, I set this code in frontend to get the token:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { AppCheck, AppCheckTokenResult, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider, getToken, initializeAppCheck } from 'firebase/app-check';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AppCheckService {
  app: FirebaseApp | undefined;
  appCheck: AppCheck;

  constructor() {
    this.app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);

    (<any>window).FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
    // Create a ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider instance using reCAPTCHA Enterprise.
    this.appCheck = initializeAppCheck(this.app, {
      provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(environment.recaptcha.siteKey),
      isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true // Set to true to allow auto-refresh.
    });
  }

  async getToken(): Promise<AppCheckTokenResult | undefined> {
    let appCheckTokenResponse;
    try {
      appCheckTokenResponse = await getToken(this.appCheck, /* forceRefresh= */ false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    return appCheckTokenResponse;
  }
}
```

As initially I don't have any kind of connection to firebase in front, I've created it, initializeApp and get a token with my recaptcha key info. This seems that works properly.

After that, I've create an interceptor in angular to send an additional param (the token) with any request and then I can work with it in the backend. This also works properly.
So, in my backend I've create a controller to verify the token sent by the front:

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { getAppCheck } from "firebase-admin/app-check";

class AppCheckController {
  /**
   * Operación encargada de verificar el token de App Check para Firebase
   */
  verifyTokenAppCheck = async (req: Request): Promise<void> => {
    const appCheckToken = req.header("X-Firebase-AppCheck");
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (appCheckToken) {
        getAppCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken).then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          res ? resolve() : reject(new Error('AppCheck: Source not authorized. Call without errors.'));
        }).catch(err => {
          reject(new Error(err.message ?? 'AppCheck: Source not authorized'))
        })
      } else {
        reject(new Error('AppCheck: Token null'))
      }
    })
  }
}

export = AppCheckController
```

The verification process return this kind of object:

```
{
  appId: '*****************************************',
  token: {
    sub: '*****************************************',
    aud: [ '************', '************' ],
    provider: 'debug',
    iss: 'https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/************',
    exp: ************,
    iat: ************,
    jti: '************************************************',
    app_id: '************************************************'
  }
}
```

Before each query I call to my controller, verify the token and then, execute the queries with firebase. The problem is that firebase queries not load response data and my app doesn't take the info from the realtime database.

When I've check my verified requests in the firebase console, shows me 0, so, it's seems that the token is not verified correctly.

Please, can you give any idea to solve this?